# Aggregating from various sources

Tags: rss, yahoo-pipes, aggregators

It could be a project well beyond my skills right now but I've got around one full month to spend on it so I think I can do it. What I want to build is this: Gather news about a specific subject from various sources. Easy, right? Just get the rss feeds and display them on a page. Well, I want something more advanced: Duplicates removed and customized presentation (that is, be able to define/change the format in which the news headlines are displayed).

I've played a bit with Yahoo Pipes and some other tools and I am facing two big problems:

1. Some sources don't provide rss feeds. How do I create one?
2. What's the best method to find and remove duplicates. I thought about comparing the headlines and checking if there is a matching bigger than, say, 50%. Is that a good practice though?

Please add any other things (problems, suggestions, whatever) I might not have considered.

Answer (score 1):

Duplication is a nasty issue.  What I eventually ended up doing:

- 1.  Strip out all HTML tags except for links (Although I started using regex, I was burned.  I eventually moved to custom parsing to remove tags)
- 2.  Strip out all whitespace
- 3.  Case-desensitize
- 4.  Hash all that with MD5.

Here's why you leave the link in:
A comment might be as simple as "Yes, this sucks".  "Yes, this sucks" could be a common comment.  BUT if the text "this sucks" is linked to different things, then it is not a duplicate comment.

Additionally, you will find that HTML tag escaping is weird with RSS feeds. You would think that a stray < would be double-encoded: (I think)&<;
But it is not.  It is encoded < 
But so too are HTML tags!

:<p>
I eventually copied all the known HTML tags as parsed by Mozilla Firefox and manually recognized those tags.

Creating an RSS feed from HTML is quite nasty and I can only point you to services such as Spinn3r, which are fantastic at de-duplication and content extraction.  These services typically use probability-based algorithms that are above me.  I know of one provider that got away with regexing pages (They had to know that a certain page was MySpace-based or Blogger-based) but they did not perform admirably.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to use the [YQL module](http://blog.pipes.yahoo.net/2009/01/28/new-pipes-yql-module-and-changes-to-use-this-pipe-banner/) to scrape a webpage that doesn't provide RSS. [Here's a sample](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A//finance.yahoo.com/q%3Fs%3Dyhoo%22%20and%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20xpath%3D%27//div%5B@id%3D%22yfi_headlines%22%5D/div%5B2%5D/ul/li/a%27) of a YQL statement to scrape HTML.

About duplicates, take a look at [this pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=4b134855ba42249762957756a78c3a1c).

Customized presentation: if you want it truly customized you'll have to manipulate the pipe results yourself, e.g. get it as JSON an manipulate it with Javascript, or process it server-side.